# Alignment issues with lists in a table in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, context, context-mkiv

This issue has been answered many times for LaTeX, but I couldn't find any explanation for ConTeXt. Here is a sample that shows the alignment problem :

```
\starttable[|cB|p(4cm)|p(4cm)|]
    \DC\DL[2]\DR
    \NC \VL \REF[cB]{Foo}
        \VL \REF[cB]{Bar}
        \VL \AR
    \HL
    \VL Things
        \VL
            \startitemize[packed]
                \item Carrot
                \item Tomato
            \stopitemize
        \VL
            \startitemize[packed]
                \item Rice
                \item Superman
                \item Onion
                \item Chocolate
            \stopitemize
        \VL\AR
    \HL
\stoptable
```

And here is the result with mkiv:

[image]

As you can see, the list on the right-most cell is not aligned properly to the top. When compiling, I'm getting a few `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected` but I have not clue how to resolve this.

Any suggestions ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table` mechanism is fairly old and is deprecated. For anything non-trivial table typesetting, it is better to use one of the modern table mechanisms like `tabulate`, `natural tables`, or `xtables`. See [ConTeXt Wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tables_Overview) for comparision of these. For the above example, I'd use natural tables (and since you don't have rows and columns that span multiple cells, you can use the simpler syntax)

```
\startsetups table
  \setupTABLE[column][first][style=bold, align=middle]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold, align=middle]
  \setupTABLE[1][1][frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][width=4cm]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][width=4cm]
\stopsetups
\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=table]
  \NC \NC Foo \NC Bar \NC \NR
  \NC Things \NC
            \startitemize[packed]
                \item Carrot
                \item Tomato
            \stopitemize
        \NC
            \startitemize[packed]
                \item Rice
                \item Superman
                \item Onion
                \item Chocolate
            \stopitemize
        \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The `TABLE` mechanism is so much simpler to use !